# LaTeX/MathJax in Google sites help

Tags: mathjax

Could someone provide me step by step procedure on how to include TeX equation in my Google site? I am not familiar with the technicalities of HTML or web-browsers and so on. I found [this website](https://sites.google.com/site/gencoreoperative/index/articles-and-hacks/google-s-latex) with info but I do not get how to do it!

I would really appreciate it your help.

Comment: mathjax-specific questions are off topic here (the {mathjax} link above suggests better places, but google sites offer a very restricted environment that does not allow additional javascript code so mathjax is not an option there.

Comment: you can use the google chart api you link to, but that isn't mathjax and produces an image that appears on your site.

Comment: Thanks. For the link I have included I do not understand how to incorporate it into google sites. In any case thanks for the info.

Comment: Just take that `<img` element with the long URL and add it to your site the formula should appear, you don't need to install or do anything

Comment: I have tried it. I copy-paste it and in the end I just see the code. Not the formula.

Comment: you need to paste it as source not into the text it's a long time since i used googlesites but the editor lets you see the html markup you need to add <img.... where you can see <p>...

Comment: Try adding this link (`http://www.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&chco=000000&chl=e^z=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{z^n}{n!}`) as an link to an image `Web address (URL)` as seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=hdGWJsY5idE#t=753